# Prove that $u \circ f $ is plurisubharmonic on $\Omega_1$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables, potential-theory

I'm trying to show that the **theorem** in my book:

> *Let $f: \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ be a **holomorphic** map between open sub - sets $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ of $\Bbb C^n$. If $u$ is **plurisubharmonic** on $\Omega_2$ ($u \in PSH(\Omega_2)$) then $u \circ f $ is plurisubharmonic on $\Omega_1$ ($u \in PSH(\Omega_1)$*).

======================================================

Assume that $u \in C^2(\Omega_2)$. I tried to show that $\forall z \in \Omega_1, \omega \in \Bbb C^n$ then $$\sum_{j,k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial^2 (u\circ f)}{\partial z_j \partial \overline{z_k}}(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k} \ge 0 \tag I$$

- Since $u \in PSH(\Omega_2)$ we have $$\sum_{j,k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_j \partial \overline{z_k}}(z)\cdot \omega_j \overline{\omega_k} \ge 0 \tag 1$$

======================================================

How can we show that $(I)$?

Any help is always appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $u$ twice differentiable, it's a simple consequence of the chain rule. Since the $f_m$ are holomorphic, the general

$$\frac{\partial (u\circ f)}{\partial z_j} = \sum_{m}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial w_m}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial z_j} + \sum_m \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{w_m}}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f_m}}{\partial z_j}$$

simplifies to

$$\frac{\partial (u\circ f)}{\partial z_j} = \sum_{m} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial w_m}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial z_j}.$$

No $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{w}_m}$ occur since the components $f_m$ are holomorphic, so $\frac{\partial \overline{f_m}}{\partial z_j} = 0$. Then differentiating with respect to $\overline{z_k}$ yields

$$\frac{\partial^2(u\circ f)}{\partial z_j\partial \overline{z_k}} = \sum_{m,n} \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial w_m \partial \overline{w_n}}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial z_j}\cdot \overline{\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial z_k}},$$

where the holomorphy of $f$ causes all terms $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z_j\partial z_k}$ to be annihilated, and for the matrix of the Levi form, you get

$$L_{u\circ f} = J_f^\ast\cdot  L_u\cdot J_f$$

(or with $\overline{J_f}$ instead of $J_f$, depends on which is the row and which the column index). If $L_u$ is positive semidefinite, any $A^\ast\cdot L_u\cdot A$ is also positive semidefinite.

Comment: @ **Daniel Fischer:** But I think that the chain rule is:
$$\frac{\partial (u\circ f)}{\partial z_j} = \sum_{m} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z_m}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial z_j}+ \sum_{m} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z_m}}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial \overline{f_m}}{\partial z_j}=\sum_{m} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \boxed{z_m}}\circ f\right)\cdot \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial z_j}$$

Comment: But the $f_m$ are holomorphic here, so $\dfrac{\partial \overline{f_m}}{\partial z_j} \equiv 0$, so the $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{w_j}}$ terms are annihilated in $\dfrac{\partial (u\circ f)}{\partial z_j}$. Similar for $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial w_j\partial w_k}$ when differentiating the second time. That's what the sentence after the first formula is meant to express. I should probably make that more explicit?

Comment: Since $f_m \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega_1) \implies \dfrac{\partial \overline{f_m}}{\partial z_j} \equiv 0$ then I see. But I don't understand Why you replace $z_m$ by $\omega_m$. Yes,You can make that more explicit! please.

Comment: Ah, the $w_m$. I just don't like to name the coordinates in the different spaces $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ by the same letter, so I arbitrarily called the ones in $\Omega_2$ $w_m$ and the ones in $\Omega_1$ I called $z_j$.

Comment: Yes, Now I see! Thank you very much! **Daniel Fischer**